# Can't add my personal Google Account to the Online Accounts on Ubuntu 23.04 or 23.10

Tags: 23.04, google

I can't add my personal Google account to the Online Accounts in Ubuntu, nor 23.04 or 23.10 (I just upgraded). The strange thing is that it's only on my personal account. With the business account I had no trouble.

The process is that I add the account, the next window appears where I add my password, but after that it just stays like waiting for confirmation and nothing happens. I add the picture here.

[image]

I looked on the Google account to see if there's any kind of lock, but I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. After entering your Google password right click the box then click reload. I was then asked for 2FA verification and I have that set up for my Google account. Once I completed that my Google account was connected.

Comment: worked for me. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. Temporarily removing my titan security key from the 2FA settings on Google Accounts got me past that loading. I assume the in-app browser it uses does not support security keys and just stalls.